# How to pass a set of filenames as arguments of a command?

Tags: bash, unix

I use `pdfunite` command to combine all my pdf files into a single pdf file. `pdfunite` has a format as follow:

```
pdfunite <PDF-sourcefile-1>..<PDF-sourcefile-N> <PDF-destfile>
```

Let say, I have 100 files ( file1.pdf, file2.pdf, .... , file100.pdf) and want to combine them into file.pdf

How can I pass all these filename into pdfunite?

I have tried like:

```
args=""
for i in {1..100}; do args=$args" ""file"$i".pdf"; done
pdfunite args file.pdf
```

but it doesn't work. Can you help?

Comment: Perhaps `pdfunite $args file.pdf`?  You need that `$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
pdfunite file{1..100}.pdf file.pdf
```

Also, in your original version, add `$` to `args` to use its value rather than its verbal meaning.

Comment: FYI, you can use `echo` to see what expansion of `file{1..100}.pdf` will be, and `file{001..100}.pdf` for further information.

Comment: @dibery: if I write echo file{1..100}.pdf in a script file, it always print out like 'file{1..100}.pdf', how can I make it in a script file?

Comment: This expansion is for bash, so if you use `sh`, this method will not work.